# Can MacOS scale 3200x1800 monitor?

Tags: macos, display, resolution

I'm thinking about buying this but i'm wondering if MacOS can properly scale this for a crisp image. For example my 2018 15 inch macbook pro scales its build in monitor so it looks like "1680x1050" so all the text looks nice and crisp. Wondering if it can do the same with this monitor.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B08GYBHYNR/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08GYBHYNR)

Answer (score 1):

MacOS can scale any monitor. It scales best to integer numbers: by default 2x scaling, so a 3200 x 1800 would scale best to half that, 1600 x 900.